# Why does loading page directly with url doesn't show the data using react?

Tags: reactjs

i have a component named items and within this component i make a request to the server to load data of items.. This works.

Now when i refresh the page the page doesn't show the loaded items.

Could someone help me understand or solve this such that the items are visible on page refresh as well.

Am i missing something in lifecycle hooks (didupdate or so)? thanks.

Below is the code,

```
export default Items extends react.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.items.length > 0) {
            this.load_items_data();
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.items !== prevProps.items && 
            this.state.items.length === 0) {
            this.load_items_data();
        }
    }

    render = () => {
        return ( 
            {this.state.items.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={item.id}>
                                    <td>{item.name</td>
                             );
            }
        );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

> Below, we loop through the numbers array using the JavaScript map()
>   function. We return a
>
> element for each item. Finally, we assign
>   the resulting array of elements to listItems:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

> We include the entire listItems array inside a  element, and
>   render it to the DOM:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: thanks but i meant on refreshing the page it doesn't show me the items data...wanted to know if i need to add something in componendidupdate method.

Comment: Usually, you will want to fetch the data in componentDidMount, which then you can use setState to update your items array. And finally, display the data using the method above. Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/1orlj72wq4

Comment: Refreshing the page will trigger componentDidMount again and again. componentDidUpdate is triggered only on subsequent changes to your props. It doesn't affect the initial render of your component.

Comment: thanks i was missing a method call in didmount works :)